# How to use multiple pipe streams

Tags: java, filter, pipe

It's a first time on writing here as a Korean. If there's are a few or a lot of grammatical error please understand thanks.

I'm trying to make a pipedinputstreams. Its about reading two txt files and filtering that files' data.

In LifeCycleManager, reading student, course files and writing in to output1,2 files.
And my professor said I can do that with arraylist to read multiple files but
I lost the way how to do this.

```
package Framework;
import Components.Middle.MiddleFilter;
import Components.Sink.SinkFilter;
import Components.Source.SourceFilter;
public class LifeCycleManager {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CommonFilter srcFilterS = new SourceFilter("Students.txt");
            CommonFilter srcFilterC = new SourceFilter("Courses.txt");
            CommonFilter sinkFilter1 = new SinkFilter("Output1.txt");
            CommonFilter sinkFilter2 = new SinkFilter("Output2.txt");
            CommonFilter middleFilter = new MiddleFilter();

            srcFilterS.connectOutputTo(middleFilter);
            srcFilterC.connectOutputTo(middleFilter);
            middleFilter.connectOutputTo(sinkFilter1);
            middleFilter.connectOutputTo(sinkFilter2);

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(srcFilterS);
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(srcFilterC);
            Thread thread3 = new Thread(middleFilter);
            Thread thread4 = new Thread(sinkFilter2);
            Thread thread5 = new Thread(sinkFilter1);

            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
            thread4.start();
            thread5.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
package Framework;

import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class CommonFilterImpl implements CommonFilter {
    protected ArrayList<PipedInputStream> in = new ArrayList<PipedInputStream>();
    protected ArrayList<PipedOutputStream> out = new ArrayList<PipedOutputStream>();

    public void connectOutputTo(CommonFilter nextFilter, int portNo) throws IOException {
        out.get(portNo).connect(nextFilter.getPipedInputStream());
    }
    public void connectInputTo(CommonFilter previousFilter, int portNo) throws IOException {
        in.get(portNo).connect(previousFilter.getPipedOutputStream());
    }
    public PipedInputStream getPipedInputStream(int portNo) {
        return in.get(portNo);
    }
    public PipedOutputStream getPipedOutputStream(int portNo) {
        return out.get(portNo);
    }
    abstract public boolean specificComputationForFilter() throws IOException;
    public void run() {
        try {
            specificComputationForFilter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (e instanceof EOFException) return;
            else System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            closePorts();
        }
    }
    private void closePorts() {
        try {
            out.get(0).close();
            in.get(0).close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: need more details where is the problem? do you get error? what are expected and actual results?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.